# incorrect method signature and call

Tags: c, pthreads

So I have a program which is supposed to have consumer and producer threads.

In the main method, I want to call `init_consumers()` which will call `ptread_init()`

Here is some code:

```
int init_consumers(char *quantity, pthread_t **cons, void *complex_obj)
{
    //seting the limit acording to "quantity"
    for (; i < limit; i++)
        pthread_create(cons[i], NULL, &consumer, &complex_obj);

    return(i);
}
```

the `main`:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#define MAX_PROD 50
#define MAX_CONS 50
///main entry point of the program
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t prod[MAX_PROD];
    pthread_t cons[MAX_CONS];
    struct complex_obj *co;

    //some code

    co = create_cplx_obj();
    //complex object manipulation code

    init_producers(argv[2], &prod, co);
    init_consumers(argv[3], &cons, co);

    //more code

    exit(0);
}
```

`argv[2]` and `argv[3]` is how many producers/consumers the user wants.

Also, the thread signature is: `void *producer(void *args);`
I still get problems with the `*` and `&`, so my problem is when making the method call and signature.

The error I was getting was

```
n_prod_n_cons.c:158:6: note: expected ‘pthread_t * {aka long unsigned int *}’ but argument is of type ‘pthread_t (*)[50] {aka long unsigned int (*)[50]}’  int init_producers(char *quantity, pthread_t *prod, void *complex_obj)
```

Comment: Call `init_producers(argv[2], prod, co)`.  Define `int init_producers(char *qty, pthread_t *cons, void *co)` and invoke `pthread_create(&cons[i], NULL, producer, co);`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, that looks better than what I was thinking.

Comment: A `T (*)[]` is not the same as a `T **`, and your compiler should have warned you about it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the compiler diagnostics messages (verbatim!) you're getting when compiling this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated (tersely) in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53023347/incorrect-method-method-signature-and-call/53023559#comment92948955_53023347), you have arrays of `pthread_t` in `main()`; pass them to the launchers just as you would an array of `int`.  Make the signature of the launcher functions match what you'd do if you passed an array of `int`.  Then use `&array[index]` to pass a pointer to a single row of the array to `pthread_create()`.  That adds up to:

In `main()`:

```
init_producers(argv[2], prod, co);
init_consumers(argv[3], cons, co);
```

(Your code was passing a `pthread_t (*)[MAX_PROD]` — pointer to a fixed size array of `pthread_t` — to the launcher functions, quite different from the signatures which expected a `pthread_t **`.)

The launchers look like:

```
int init_consumers(char *quantity, pthread_t *cons, void *complex_obj)
{
    // setting the limit acording to "quantity"
    for (; i < limit; i++)
        pthread_create(&cons[i], NULL, consumer, &complex_obj);

    return(i);
}
```

`cons[i]` is the `i`<sup>th</sup> entry in the array of `pthread_t`; passing its address give the `pthread_create()` function the `pthread_t *` it expects.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and the explanation, it looks like that solved the problem. `pthread_t *cons` was the key